# How to transform unordered list to one row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a word document with lists which I'm turning into a pandas dataframe. The document is made up of lists, something like:

Item1: abc

a=2

bc=01

Item2: abd

bd=12

Item3: abt

I have been able to pull this data into a table like this:

```
d = {'item': ['item1','item1','item1','item2', 'item2', 'item3'], 'description': ['abc', 'a=2', 'bc=01', 'abd',' bd=12',  'abt']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

But the goal is to create a table like this:

```
d2 = {'item': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'description': ['abc', 'abd', 'abt'], 'labels': ["'a=2', 'bc=01'", 'bd=12', np.nan]}
good_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I was originally planning to:

1. set the item column as an index
2. split the dataframe in 2: one only with rows that don't have an equal sign, the other with the rows that have the equal sign
3. turn the rows into a list
4. append list to new column in split-dataframe-1

```
# split df
split_df_1 = df[~df['labels'].str.contains("=")]
split_df_2 = df[df['labels'].str.contains("=")]

# set new index
split_df_2 = df[df['labels'].str.contains("=")].set_index('item')

split_df_2.loc('item1')
```

and this is where I'm stuck. I get the error "No axis named item1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>"

Any help with this error, or cleaner way to accomplish this task, would be super helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error you're getting is due to the use of parentheses instead of square brackets.

```
split_df_2.loc('item1')

# Should be
split_df_2.loc['item1']
```

This should create your intended output. First we extract the "label" rows, then we combine rows that share the same `item`

```
d = {'item': ['item1','item1','item1','item2', 'item2', 'item3'], 'description': ['abc', 'a=2', 'bc=01', 'abd',' bd=12',  'abt']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

label_mask = df["description"].str.contains("=")
new_labels = (df.loc[label_mask, :]
              .groupby("item")
              .apply(lambda g: ", ".join(g["description"]))
              
print(new_labels)
item
item1    a=2, bc=01
item2         bd=12
dtype: object
```

Now we can just add it to the "description" only rows to create the final DataFrame.

```
new_df = (df.loc[~label_mask, :]      # Select the correct "description" rows
          .set_index("item")          # Change the index to be the item so our DataFrame aligns with our `new_labels` Series
          .assign(labels=new_labels)) # Add `new_labels` as its own column

print(new_df)
      description      labels
item                         
item1         abc  a=2, bc=01
item2         abd       bd=12
item3         abt         NaN
```